# iOS - Override UIActivityIndicatorView's default color for the entire application

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am developing an hybrid application in javascript for iOS. And I don't have access to the underlying framework, which shows the UIActivityIndicatorView. I want to change the colour of the indicator either programmatically or setting some properties.

PS: I could do this in Android by setting themes. Hoping for a similar way, as I am new to iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the colors globally via [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance), e. g.:

```
[[UIActivityIndicatorView appearance] setColor:[UIColor red]];
```

or the same in Swift 4:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView.appearance().color = .red
```